# Ubuntu dropdown menu is all white

Tags: menu

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and all my dropdown menus are completely white, I have to hover over each option to read it! I have looked elsewhere and can't find a solution. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Any  help? I would like this solved